# Generate group by condition on row value in column R data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I want to split a data.table in R into groups based on a condition in the value of a row. I have searched SO extensively and can't find an efficient data.table way to do this (I'm not looking to for loop across rows)

I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table( x=1:139, t=c(rep(c(1:5),10),120928,rep(c(6:10),9), 10400,rep(c(13:19),6)))
```

I'd like to group at the large numbers (over a settable value) and come up with the example below:

```
dt.desired <- data.table( x=1:139, t=c(rep(c(1:5),10),120928,rep(c(6:10),9), 10400,rep(c(13:19),6)), group=c(rep(1,50),rep(2,46),rep(3,43)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt1[ , group := cumsum(t > 200) + 1]

dt1[t > 200]
#     x      t group
# 1: 51 120928     2
# 2: 97  10400     3
dt.desired[t > 200]
#     x      t group
# 1: 51 120928     2
# 2: 97  10400     3
```

Comment: Or `dt1[, g := .GRP, by=cumsum(t > 100)]`

Comment: @Frank Cool idea! A little slower on my computer. Is there a benefit to using `.GRP` here?

Comment: Nope, just don't have to think about arithmetic (the + 1), since .GRP starts counting from 1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a test like `t>100` to find the large values. You can then use `cumsum()` to get a running integer for each set of rows up to (but not including) the large number.

```
# assuming you can define "large" as >100
dt1[ , islarge := t>100]
dt1[ , group := shift(cumsum(islarge))]
```

I understand that you want the large number to be part of the group above it. To do this, use `shift()` and then fill in the first value (which will be NA after `shift()` is run.

```
# a little cleanup 
# (fix first value and start group at 1 instead of 0)
dt1[1, group := 0]
dt1[ , group := group+1]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it solves the question.